# How to enable authentication logs in Firebird 2.5?

Tags: security, logs, firebird

I downloaded Firebird 2.5 from the [official website](https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/) and installed on a Linux machine. The install location is `/opt/firebird`.

I want to be able to view authentication attempt logs for security reasons (for example, to allow tools like `fail2ban` to detect and block possible brute force attacks).

However, for some reason, `/opt/firebird/firebird.log` does not log authentication failures. I also checked `/var/log/syslog` and did not find any Firebird log.

How do I configure Firebird 2.5 to log authentication attempts?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to enable authentication failure logs (which is enough for using `fail2ban`).

Firebird 2.5 has a [trace services feature](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/doc/README.trace_services) which logs various server events, such as errors (which includes authentication errors).

You first have to edit `/opt/firebird/fbtrace.conf` and change the following lines:

```
...
# default database section
#
<database>
        # Do we trace database events or not
        enabled false
        #       ^^^^^ Change to true
...
```

And:

```
...
        # Put errors happened
        #log_errors false
       #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Uncomment and change to true
...
```

After this, add the following line to `/opt/firebird/firebird.conf`:

```
AuditTraceConfigFile = /opt/firebird/fbtrace.conf
```

Then, you have to create the log file `/opt/firebird/default_trace.log` (which Firebird didn't automatically create for me) using:

```sh
touch /opt/firebird/default_trace.log
```

Then make sure all Firebird files have the correct owner and group:

```sh
chown -R firebird:firebird /opt/firebird
```

Then restart Firebird server using:

```sh
systemctl restart firebird
```

Now `/opt/firebird/default_trace.log` will log authentication errors.

This is a log line(s) example:

```
2022-10-28T16:31:11.7300 (1313:0x7fd691ca1cc0) ERROR AT jrd8_attach_database
        database_path (ATT_0, user, UTF8, TCPv4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/[source port])
335544472 : Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.
```

---

Although unrelated to this question, here's my `fail2ban` configuration for Firebird 2.5:

`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/firebird.conf`:

```ini
# Fail2Ban filter for unsuccesfull firebird authentication attempts

[Init]
maxlines = 3

[Definition]

datepattern = ^%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S

failregex = ^.*ERROR.*\n.*TCPv4:<HOST>\/\d+\)\n\d+ : Your user name and password are not defined\. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login\.$

ignoreregex =
```

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```ini
[firebird]
enabled = true
filter = firebird
action = iptables[name=firebird, port="3050", protocol=tcp]
logpath = /opt/firebird/default_trace.log
maxretry = 5
findtime = 60
bantime = 86400
```